# JavaScript createElement() Method

Tags: javascript

What changes should i make to create buttons in the next line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you want the button to be shown in the next line, simply add a `br` element.

```
<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var br = document.createElement("br");
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(br)
document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
</script>
```

Is this what you are looking for?